# Selenium docker-compose download file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

When I run the code with `Chrome` driver, the file is downloaded as needed.

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        chrome_options=chrome_options
    )
```

When I run the code from the `Remote` driver, the file is not downloaded:

```
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
          command_executor='http://hub:4444/wd/hub',
          desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities,
    )
```

```
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.14.0-gallium
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.14.0-gallium
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      - local_chrome_data_download:/tmp/downloads
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
```

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to make a writable directory using `:rw`

```
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.14.0-gallium
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      - local_chrome_data_download:/tmp/downloads:rw
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
```